# How to get metrics of AR effect or AR frame published on facebook?

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality

I have published AR effect and Frame. I want to know the Metrics of effect which gives information about how many times it is used and how many users are using it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some metrics available from the [Camera Effects Platform page](https://www.facebook.com/fbcameraeffects/home/). If you click on the **Manage** button at the top of the page you will see all the frames you have created and how many users are using them.